# Google Drive Api Client: How to get the list of files in a folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

In a web application based on Python webapp2 I am trying to retrieve the list of files contained in a folder of the google drive account of a logged user in this way

```
 if page_token:
     param['pageToken'] = page_token
 files = service.files().list(**param).setQ("'"+self.requet.get('folder')+"' in parents").execute(http)
```

I have followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

the problem is that I get this error:

```
 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'setQ'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the 'q' param to your param variable instead of using .setQ, along the lines of:

```
param['q'] = "'root' in parents"
```